# Entity manager has not been injected Spring Aspect Jar on remote host OpenShift

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jboss, openshift

I get the following error while trying to run my application on remote server (OpenShift)
 Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

HTTP Status 500 - Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)

I have Spring aspects configured in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

ApplicationContext

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

To deploy the application i am using JBoss and open shift application.

This project is working corretly while running on local host using STS Vmware Fabric tC based on Tomcat.